# Pointer to Self, how?

Tags: delphi

```
type 
  TMyClass = class
  type
    PMyClass = ^TMyClass;
    TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: PmyClass) of object;
  public
    FTest: TMyEvent;
    procedure Test;
  end;

procedure TMyClass.Test;
begin
  FTest(@Self); //error!
end;
```

How do I do it?

Comment: You do it exactly like that. That code compiles on my D2010. I'm not sure why you would want to do that though.

Comment: @pop33 Self is already a pointer... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @pop33: If you aren't quite sure about what you are doing, you probably wish to use `Sender: TMyObject` instead. As @jachguate points out, an object variable is essentially already a "pointer".

Comment: @David: I guess the problem is that "it" isn't particularly well-defined.

Comment: Yes I know that classes are pointers. I did a hack and wanted to optimize it a bit. It seems I did a mistake, the code above compiles fine.

Comment: You don't need to send a pointer to a object. Just send the object, it is already a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What in the world are you trying to do? Of course you cannot call `FTest` since you haven't assigned any `TMyEvent` to it yet! And are `PMyClass` and `TMyEvent` really supposed to be parts of `TMyClass`?

At least this works perfectly:

```
type
  PMyClass = ^TMyClass;
  TMyClass = class;

  TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: PMyClass) of object;

  TMyClass = class
  private
    FEvent: TMyEvent;
    FSomeValue: string;
  public
    property OnSomething: TMyEvent read FEvent write FEvent;
    property SomeValue: string read FSomeValue write FSomeValue;
    procedure Test;
  end;

  TSomeOtherClass = class
  public
    class procedure MyEvent(Sender: PMyClass);
  end;

...

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  o: TMyClass;
begin

  o := TMyClass.Create;
  o.SomeValue := 'This is a test.';
  o.OnSomething := TSomeOtherClass.MyEvent;

  o.Test;
end;

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.Test;
begin
  FEvent(@Self);
end;

{ TSomeOtherClass }

class procedure TSomeOtherClass.MyEvent(Sender: PMyClass);
begin
  ShowMessage(TMyClass(Sender^).SomeValue);
end;
```

Of course, you can also have the `TMyEvent` in the same object:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private type
    PMyClass = ^TMyClass;
    TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: PMyClass) of object;
  private
    FEvent: TMyEvent;
    FSomeValue: string;
  public
    procedure TheEventHandler(Sender: PMyClass);
    property OnSomething: TMyEvent read FEvent write FEvent;
    property SomeValue: string read FSomeValue write FSomeValue;
    procedure Test;
  end;

...

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  o: TMyClass;
begin

  o := TMyClass.Create;
  o.SomeValue := 'This is a test.';
  o.OnSomething := o.TheEventHandler;

  o.Test;
end;

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.Test;
begin
  FEvent(@Self);
end;

procedure TMyClass.TheEventHandler(Sender: PMyClass);
begin
  ShowMessage(TMyClass(Sender^).SomeValue);
end;
```

Comment: @Andreas It's very normal to declare types that are private to a class to restrict their scope and avoid namespace pollution. Delphi doesn't have much namespace functionality. I took the //error! to mean a compiler error.

Comment: @David: I know that. I did that earlier today, you know. But I got the impression the logic dictates that the event type should be outside the class.

Comment: @Andreas I love private type declarations and my old D6 codebase is moving in that direction.

Comment: +1 Make it 25. Although I'm disappointed there were no graphics. ;)

Comment: @David: You must be tired: 15! = 15*14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 is a much greater number than 15.

Comment: @Andreas Not even Jon Skeet has that much rep!